# C# MVVM Add Xaml-Image to UserControl by drag&drop

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, drag-and-drop

I have a UserControl which is essentially an image of a folder. I want to drag an Image on that UserControl and have it added to the "folder" along with its ViewModel.
I want to do this with MVVM, but I am new to it and I'm having trouble. I'm just gonna list some questions. Thank you for your help.

- I am fairly certain dragging is a job of the View, so the code for
  that goes there, right?
- I can move an image around this way, but I don't know how to add the
  image to the UserControl. Where would that code go?
- What event can I use and how would I go about adding the image (and
  ViewModel) to the UserControl?
- Do I add the image(View) to the UserControl(View)'s ItemControl which
  binds to a list of imageVMs   and that does it? Or do I have to add
  it to the list of imageVMs somewhere else too?
- Is binding events to ViewModel commands okay?

I know bindings and commands, but I have no idea what to do when my business logic depends on information from the View. I need to know where an Image is in the Window.

Comment: This is going to be very complex. I'd suggest snagging https://github.com/punker76/gong-wpf-dragdrop and start with a simple prototype of an image dropped onto a canvas.